# How can I create dynamically HTML pages for each data?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create html elements for multiple datas.
I searched, then I found this document.getElementById("div-1").appendChild(container);

customer.js file:

```
    datas.forEach(function (data) {
       
        var rptContainer = document.querySelector('.container').cloneNode(true);
            
        rptContainer .querySelector('.customer-no').textContent = data.customerNo;
        rptContainer .querySelector('.customer-name').textContent =data.customerName;

          document.getElementById("div-1").appendChild(rptContainer);
      });
```

It creates elements according to the number of data, but all the pages contain the information of the most recent data.
How can I create elements according to each data (customer)?

Example of HTML file:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="div-1">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="pageContent">
            <table class="table-customer-info">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1"><span class="font-weight- 
        bold">Customer No:</span></td>
                    <td colspan="1"><span class="customer-no"></span></td>
                    <td colspan="1"><span class="font-weight-bold">Customer Name:</span></td>
                    <td colspan="1"><span class="customer-name"></span></td>
                </tr>
             </table>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="customer.js?v=24"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you getting `datas` on this particular test page?

Comment: Want to create HTML pages or HTML elements for each data?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted in the question? (Other than the use of `var`, but that could be replaced easily enough with either `let` or `const`, and probably isn't a problem in this specific instance.) Also, what's the (**relevant**) "*[mcve]*" code that you're working with (HTML, JavaScript, CSS...)?

Comment: I'm getting datas with api. @Teemu

Comment: The answer depends on the data structure the API returns. We'll need a bunch of more details to understand what you actually need. Is the data the same for all pages or does it contain page specific data only? How are you differentiating the pages when calling API etc.

Comment: @M DEV I want to create elements as you say, edited my question.

Comment: @David Thomas I'm setting variables for each data, it always shows the latest data on all pages.

Comment: My api returns an array. Example: [
    {
        "customerNo": "0001",
        "customerName": "Example Customer"
    },
    {
        "customerNo": "0002",
        "customerName": "Example Customer 2"
    }
      
] I want to show the data at the first index of the array on the first page, then show the data at the second index on the second page. According to the array I gave as an example; my code creates two pages but shows the latest index on both pages. @Teemu

Comment: Can you also show the second page in the HTML example in the question? I guess  `.container` element reresents a "page", but just to be sure. And please edit the question to contain the data example, comments are not suitable for question information.

Comment: The question falls back to "_How are you getting `datas`_", as your code seems to [work as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/2t4r0dys/). I suppose you've to fetch different data for each page, if you want to get different data.